# Why do we need a model.py for an app to be identified as Django app

Tags: django

Dear Devs around the globe ,

I would appreciate some insights on why we normaly see such line in an empty model file , most probably in a 3rd party app or so , saying
"Empty model, but so django know/interact/identify our app."

What's in django responsible for such models.py discovery , how it operates ?

& Why not the same with the views.py for example?

Best regards;

Comment: FWIW, it's all about to change in Django 1.7, so models.py won't be needed for app discovery any more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/

Comment: Yea,i read so. I'm mainly interested on "How it works" , as a way to get closer to some of the python magic at work maybe. Thanks

Comment: have a look in `django.db.models.loading` source code